# How to call an existing stored procedure from Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, postgresql, stored-procedures

I am writing an app using .net Web Api, Entity Framework and PostgreSql and I am having trouble calling a stored procedure. I've tried to go off of this question: [using stored procedure in entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970416/using-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework) but it doesn't seem to help so I'll ask for my specific case and hope I can get help.

I have written a stored procedure in postgres and all I want to do is call it from my repository. What is the best way to go about doing this? If I want to call it though a `DbContext` object do I need to tell the `DbContext` that the stored procedure exists before I call it? Would it just be better to use ado.Net to use sql directly? This is what I tried and it gives me a syntax error:

```
var serverName = new PgSqlParameter("server_name", server);
        var dt = new PgSqlParameter("data_tag", dataTag);
        var timestamp = new PgSqlParameter("ts", DateTime.Now);
        var val = new PgSqlParameter("val", value);

        if (context.Database.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            context.Database.Connection.Open();

        try
        {
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"EXEC [dbo].[historical_tag_values_insert]", serverName, dt, timestamp, val);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (context.Database.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                context.Database.Connection.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Are you following a database-first approach? If so, why not just add the stored procedure to the database model and just call it on the context object?

Comment: Where, exactly, do you get a syntax error?

Comment: It says "syntax error at or near EXEC". And I am building this for a client so I guess technically we are doing a database first approach. How would I add the stored procedure to the model? What exactly do you mean by that, like add it to the context object?