# Creating an time-intensive view as part of Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have been tasked with converting a spreadsheet in excel to an editable grid in MVC.

I can create the view just fine (takes about 14 seconds to run), but since I am using a temporary table to build the view Entity framework throws a fit. (Sorry I forget the actual error I received)

I am using a temporary table because each column's value depends on the previous column's value, for instance...

```
ColF = foo(ColA, ColB)
ColG = foo2(ColA,ColF)
ColM = foo3(ColG,ColA,ColC)
```

If I did it without a temporary table I would end up with something like this...

```
ColM = foo3(foo2(ColA,foo(ColA, ColB)),ColA,ColC)
```

This gets very messy and hard to understand so editing the query in the future will be almost impossible. Also, keep in mind that I have almost 50 columns, all building off each other.

Is there a way I can use a materialized view with a temporary table and MVC's Entity Framework, or something else? If not, it takes forever to load.

Comment: How do you plan to store the edited grid?  Materializing a representation of the data is only half of the issue.

Comment: They would only be able to edit the columns that feed into the formulas which are indeed saved into normal tables

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform this calculation on the database server, you can build and emit that temporary table out through a stored procedure.

EF can build an entity from that:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx

edit: And here's a stack overflow link about it:
[using stored procedure in entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970416/using-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework)