# Sql Stored proc and Entity framework 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-6

Suppose i have a one parameter stored procedure :

```
procedure dbo.MyStoredProc @param VARCHAR(50)
as 
SELECT *
FROM whatever
WHERE column = @param
```

In my web application (mvc with **entity 6**) i wish to call my stored procedure, and retreive all the line from it's `SELECT` statement.

```
 var DBLines = MyStoredProc(parameterValue);
```

I saw something disappointing but very logic; **my var was containing an integer.** That integer was 1. It was telling me that everything went ok in my stored procedure...

I want that var to **contains every SQL lines my stored proc went through**. I suppose it is possible but how ? There must be a commun logic. All i saw on internet... was workarounds.

Comment: you miss lot of information. maybe check this question first. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970416/using-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework

Comment: Already saw that, and it isin't very clear, plus i usualy don't need any model to acces my datas. There must be a way to just call the stored proc and take everything it selected. anyway i'm going to try that for now

Comment: well the idea behind MVC is you should have a model. But if you read below will show how to call it with a parameter. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20972897/3470178

Comment: Yeah thats more like it, it's not working yet but i should be able to fix it, thank you

Comment: Did you import the stored procedure as a *Function*? Have a look at this question also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32140774/getting-data-from-stored-procedure-with-entity-framework

Comment: Thanks @S.Akbari I'm going to take a look at it.

Comment: @S.Akbari in both case, mine and the case mentionned, you'r going to need an sql object that ilustrate your stored procedre result, in the case you mentionned, the OP already had an sql object that looked like his stored procedure result. So yeah, in this case, it was a good solution. But in my case, i had no object representing my stored proc result. So i had to create one anyway, now that it's done, i can use both tehcnique, mine and the one in the question you mentionned

Comment: *I can use both tehcnique, mine and the one in the question you mentionned*...from *mine* did you mean one that you mentioned in the accepted answer below?

Comment: Yes, i answered my own question, my things work now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lots of frustrations, i found a way, but it's another work around. This one works pretty well for me though, and it does not require extra C# code, no model, and no such things as `public class FunctionsContext : BaseContext<FunctionsContext>{}` whatever that is...

In SQL Server, i created an empty table that looks just like the return of my stored procedure. Suppose my stored procedure was to return  :

```
SELECT nvarchar(2), int, datetime FROM whatever WHERE <condition>
```

Then my Empty_Table is created with the same var types. After mapping my Empty_Table with Entity framework mapping wizard. I could use it as a type to to this :

```
databaseEntities db = new databaseEntities();

var query = db.Database.SqlQuery<Empty_Table>("EXEC [dbo].[My_Stored_Proc] @p1", new SqlParameter("p1", parameterValue));

foreach (var line in query)
{
    int i = line.ID
}
```

And it worked perfectly. This is going to be my main (only) technique for using stored procedure with Entity.

**EDIT (SOLVED CORRECTLY) :**

Issu as been completely solved in the latest version of entity, if you put your EDMX file inside the Model folder, then you can import the stored procedure in the contextual menu. EF will automatically do 3 things :

1. Create a new complexe object representing the result of the stored procedure named `result_NameOfStoredProc`.
2. Place the procedure's definition in the model.
3. Create a function to use the stored procedure.

So no more work-around. That's the way to go.

**EDIT 2 (bog)**

For some reason, my first edit (good solution) got broken as soon as I introduce a temporary table in my stored procedure.

I am able to import my stored procedure correctly only if it doesn't contain a temporary table, I tested it by

1. deleting my complexes types, fonctions importations, and Procedure from my `.edmx` file in the model folder.
2. Adding these two lines in the stored procedure :

   `CREATE TABLE #TableVariable (cmpt nvarchar(18))`

   `insert into #TableVariable select  cmpt from TA where NomReseau = @user`
3. Re-import the procedure using `.edmx` file's contextual menu

And boom. No more `result_NameOfStoredProc` object created... An annoying int instead, JUST LIKE BEFORE. I had to modify the whole query to replace all call to this temporary table to something else (logically, a variable table), then save it, then import, then change the procedure back... Much fun... This is a disaster.

**Edit 3 (bog)**

Well... I have another bog where entity isn't able to create the result object I need, I think it's because the database I use is older than my others. So I created a class to compensate and I used the code of my first solution. Sometimes there is no other way. I would like Entity to always work like in my first edit, but I just CAN'T count on that.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this issue is trough creating a temptable->inserting result into temp table -> select from temp table

then delete all objects related to this stored procedure on your project and update from database checking again this procedure

also use the `SET NOCOUNT ON;` on your sp