# Entity framework - SP Returned value

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Working on my first mvc(5) asp.net web application. I am using data entity framework. I have a stored procedure, 'usp_EventInsert' which takes HevEventID, HemEmployeID and HevEventDescription:

```
@HevEventID int,
@HemEmployeID int,
@HevEventDescription varchar(150)

SET NOCOUNT ON
SET XACT_ABORT ON

INSERT INTO [dbo].[RhEvent] ([HevEventID],[HemEmployeID],[HevEventDescription])
SELECT @HevEventID, @HemEmployeID, @HevEventDescriptionID
```

In my code, I want to insert an event in the table and check if it was successful. I am calling it this way, for example:

```
myDBcontext.usp_EventInsert(123,112345,"some description")
```

I was expecting to be able to fetch the HevEventID(or HemEmployeID or HevEventDescriptionID) once the stored procedure is called. For example, I tried:

```
var event = myDBcontext.usp_EventInsert(123,112345,"some description")
```

I was expecting to find the elements in the select inside 'event'. But event = -1 when I try that.  Not only event doesn't have any of the select data in it, it's value is -1(From what I read SET NOCOUNT ON causes that?), which seems odd to me since the stored procedure was successful (new row being inserted in the table).

any suggestions on how I can be sure the stored procedure was successful? Without doing a select on the table..

Comment: Make your SP return a negative status code for error and the inserted ID if successfull.

Comment: Did you managed to solve your problem? if not i may give you an answer adapted directly to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like i answered in this previous questions:

[ORA-01722: invalid number on Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39205825/ora-01722-invalid-number-on-entity-framework/39212614#39212614)

Being sure that your stored procedure worked properly **and obtain the RETURN** you wanted from it can be quite a trick with Entity. I won't suggest you any precise methode of doing so. But i will strongly suggest you read all these links question/answer :

[using stored procedure in entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970416/using-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework/20972897#20972897)

[Getting data from stored procedure with Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32140774/getting-data-from-stored-procedure-with-entity-framework)

[Sql Stored proc and Entity framework 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37617199/sql-stored-proc-and-entity-framework-6/37754120#37754120)

If you haven't found your way out of it with one of the methode i provided you, explain what is the problem concerning the methode you've used and i'm sure we can fix this.