# how to run stored procedure in Entity framework

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a Query in Database which is bringing another query in response using Json via Ajax. I have created the stored procedure which is accepting that query and bringing multiple columns.

I am not getting how to run stored procedure in entity framework.

Help needed.

Method:-

```
public ActionResult DropDownn(string query)
    {
        using (DynamicDBEntities db = new DynamicDBEntities())
        {
            //var dbQuery = db.Database.SqlQuery<Cust_mas>(query).ToList();
            //return Json(courseList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

SP:-
    alter procedure [dbo].[SP_DynamicCtrl]

```
@query nvarchar(1000) 
As
begin
execute sp_executesql @query;
end
```

Comment: try this: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/stored-procedure-in-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using stored procedure in entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970416/using-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework)

Comment: @DanielTshuva It is using a model which I don't want to use. i directly want to return that data in json and print it in table

Comment: your stored procedure return a json?

Comment: @DanielTshuva no...... actually stored procedure is sending multiple columns but I want to return in JSON form so that ajax call can execute them.

Comment: if so you need to get data from the stored procedure into some model and then return the model to the client - you will get the model in json format

Comment: @DanielTshuva Actually I want like there is method.... please see the edit
there is a method "DropDown which is returning data from the database and taking a parameter which contains a query that is coming from ajax"

i just want to execute the query and print the result on HTML screen

Comment: @DanielTshuva ???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per my understanding, you want to execute a stored procedure that run on multiple tables, and then return Json Data to View. You can actually do something like below:

**Approach 1**: (Using ExecuteSqlCommand)

```
SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@query", query);        
var result = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SP_DynamicCtrl @query", 
                              param1);
```

**Approach 2:** (Using Object Type on SqlQuery)

```
SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@query", query);
Var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<Object>("exec SP_DynamicCtrl @query", param1);
```

**Approach 3:** (Cleaner Approach)

1.) Create a model as per your return parameters from stored procedure, let's call it `YourType` class.
2.) Use the below code to call stored pocedure:

```
SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@query", query);
Var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<YourType>("exec SP_DynamicCtrl @query", param1);
```

After you get the result from above query, you can convert it to JSON befor returning in controller:

```
return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); //Typecast the result as per your need
```

Please modify code as per your need.

Comment: can I pass my query parameter inside SqlQuery() method ..... as my sp is accepting the parameter and executing it.

it is also showing error

Comment: In my example shown above, @query is the parameter of stored procedure. What error are you getting after using above code?

Comment: It is not accepting Functions ... unknown "Functions"

Comment: @sandeepgupta: I have updated the answer. Please take a look and verify.

Comment: 1. Showing result = -1
2. Showing: - The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection.
3. I don't want to use model I directly want to use json result to generate table

Answer (score 0):

if you have mapped it in the edmx try this

```
 public ActionResult DropDownn(string query)
    {
        using (DynamicDBEntities db = new DynamicDBEntities())
        {

       var result = context.SP_DynamicCtrl(query);
        return result.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The data reader returned by the store data provider does not have enough columns for the query requested

Comment: it is showing error in "var result = context.SP_DynamicCtrl(query);"
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int64' type to the 'System.String' type is not valid.'

Comment: try with a public static string

Comment: the result is returning casting issue